# Server Trust Issue In production Environment

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, https, nsurlconnection

We are testing our app is in production and today we came across an issue "The Certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “server.name” which could put your confidential information at risk.

We are using connection over https and SSL certificates are also valid.

This happening only some times and not reproducible always.

From client side when asked for `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust`, `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` is returning NO.

Then the following error is logged in

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
      didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
           [error localizedDescription],
           [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
```

Error Logged is:

```
Connection failed! Error - The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “server.name” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

Server certificates are issued by COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA.

Comment: Perhaps you're being intermittently MITMed!

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

- certificate isn't really completely valid

  - time has expired, or local clock is wrong
  - you are accessing in a way that makes the host invalid, subnet isn't covered by cert, etc
- you are using a rewriting proxy, ie Charles, so the current cert isn't your servers cert.
- cert isn't being vended by server correctly.
- other software bug!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do we need to do any thing from client side connection.? This is for iPhone.

Comment: @nkongara you need either a valid certificate on the server -- OR you need to ignore this on the client side. (Id go with a good certificate)

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Problem is this is happening in some devices/simulators and only intermittently.  We verified that certificates are valid on the server.  We can't ignore this on client side in production environment(AuthenticationChallenge handling is not there for prod environment)

Comment: check if server time and client time match :)

Comment: Well I have provided possible causes, if @nkongra can post some logs or error codes, then I could narrow it down.

Comment: @Grady: Thanks for the reply. I updated question with some extra info from client side.

Comment: see what the errors code and domain are, also log out the NSURLConnection object( to make sure the host is the host you think it is, and not somethingelse.yourhost.domain)